# Store SQL field as a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to select some fields from my database and store them as a variable so I can use them to display data on my page. So far I have this:

```
  protected void DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstName;
        GridViewRow row = DefaultGrid.SelectedRow;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[9].Text);
        string checkStatement = "Return fName FROM SecureOrders WHERE IdentityColumn LIKE @identity";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        using (SqlCommand _check = new SqlCommand(checkStatement, connection))
        {
            _check.Parameters.Add("@identity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            connection.Open();
            _check.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

I'm wondering how I should alter this so that I can save the field fName in the variable called firstName. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you mean `SELECT fName ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `firstName = (string) _check.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only returning 1 row and 1 field. You should use ExecuteScalar.

If you're going to return more than that, use a DataReader and ExecuteReader.

You should also place your connection within a using statement like your command.
Your sql statememnt should be Select Field1, Field2..n from Table where X=@Variable

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but as far as how you plan to save the field should be determined by what you want to do with it once you've retrieved it. Are you going to display it? What are you going to display it in? [Here's](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/2/) some basic syntax for a few scenarios. If you want more a more explicit answer, give a little more detail in your question.

Comment: It's going to be displayed in an html table. I am basically trying to select a whole column, but display each field from that column in it's own row in my html table.

Comment: Reader will be faster than adapter, but if you don't want to write a lot of code, then use adapter as you will get DataTable which you can easily loop through and build your own html table. You can build HtmlTable and render it to page. Take a look at this [example](http://www.csharpest.net/?p=89) or if you decide to use another type of element like a div, you could use [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) where you can create any element you want like: new HtmlGenericControl("div");

Comment: If you're just wanting to see the basics of ado, formatting and structure of the code [read here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/lesson01.aspx)